# remove duplicate element of array with coffescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have an array with elements duplicates:

```
data = ["Ruby on rails", "Ruby on rails", "Jquery", "Coffescript", "Javascript"]
```

I try to remove duplicate elements of array with

```
indexes = []
uniques = []
i = 0
while i < data.length
 if indexes[data[i].text] is "undefined"
  indexes[data[i].text] = "defined"
  uniques.push
i++
console.log data
```

But I get the same result with elements duplicates.

How can I fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: Short of me fixing your code for you I'd recommend a library like underscore.js
it's great for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> … is "undefined"
> ```

does get compiled to `=== "undefined"`, which is not what you want. Remove the quotes for not comparing against the string, but the `undefined` value.

Btw, your script should be

```
index = {}
uniques = []

for text in data
 unless (text of index)
  index[text] = true
  uniques.push(text)
```

or even a filter comprehension like

```
index = {}
uniques = for text in data when not (text of index)
 index[text] = true
 text
```

Comment: If I remove the do `"undefined"` and add `undefined` from `if indexes[data[i].text]` is undefined I get `[][][][][]` Thanks!